# Removing index.php from my URLs in Codeigniter 2

Tags: .htaccess

I have a codeigniter installation in the root's sub folder, the current URL to access my application is like:

```
http://www.site.com/subfolder/index.php/controller/action
```

I want to remove `index.php` from URL, so I created a `.htaccess` file and the file looks like below;

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And I also have edited

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'root';
```

To:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Then I tried URL:

```
www.site.com/subfolder/controller/action
```

But it shows a `Not found` error page, I got the page working when I edited the URL to:

```
www.site.com/subfolder/?/controller/action
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```